# JUnit test compile error while migrating from Spring Boot lower to higher version

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I recently migrated from from Spring Boot lower (2.1.7.RELEASE) to higher version (2.5.5)
and all of a sudden my JUnit test class which was compiling fine earlier started showing compile error for import statements like import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

Comment: What did you tried so far.. ? Whether it is showing in IDE.. ? Did you try to build the project through terminal.. ? Or Restart the terminal. Post the Complete error description and also elaborate your question little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally we should update the test case as per new version guidelines.

However to quickly fix the compile issue, I just added following dependency org.junit.vintage / junit-vintage-engine in pom.xml, which resolved the issue.